# How to redirect url from the datagridview asp

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

this is my code for the rowdatabound event on asp gridview

```
 protected void jobGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            (e.Row.FindControl("TitleLink") as LinkButton).Attributes.Add("onClick", "RedirectPage('" + jobListTable.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex + (jobGridView.PageIndex * 10)]["job_id"].ToString() + "')");

        }
    }
```

my java script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RedirectPage(ID) {

        window.location = "Login.aspx";
    }
</script>
```

However, my code doesn't work, can someone tell me why?

Comment: What happens when you click on the linkbutton? And what error you get in console (if you get any)? And if you're redirecting to `Login.aspx` hardcoded, why are you passing a parameter?

Comment: I thought the javascript should be `window.location.href = "xxx";` ?? Then is should be `return false` cause `linkbutton` will do a `postback`. Another thing is why need `javascript` since using `linkbutton`

Comment: Doesn't show anything, i pass parameter because i intend to put a querystring behind the link, but current this is my testing code, and to me, i use window.location.href the result is still same. why i need javascript is because i want to passing parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `LinkButton` is a server control. If you want to bind to the javascript function, instead of `onClick` you should target `onClientClick`. Also to prevent postback you should `return false` from the javascript function.

Find below code (to make things simple I've removed the parameter in the javascript function; you could apply it according to your needs)

C# code behind (note the `onClientClick` part)

```
    protected void jobGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            (e.Row.FindControl("TitleLink") as LinkButton).OnClientClick = "javascript:return RedirectPage();";
        }
    }
```

javascript function (note the `return false` part)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RedirectPage() {
        window.location = 'Login.aspx';
        return false;
    }
</script>
```